# Why is absolute positioning making the background of the paragraph elements shrink?

Tags: html, css, css-position

When the div container that contains the paragraph elements is given relative positioning the background color covers all the paragraphs completely and it should because paragraphs are block elements, but if the position is set to absolute the background color kind of shrinks to only the paragraphs and not the length of the browser.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

div#container {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#p1 {
  background-color: #A52A2A;
  position: relative;
}

#p2 {
  background-color: #DEB887;
  position: relative;
  top: 65px;
  left: 65px;
}

#p3 {
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
}

#p4 {
  background-color: #FF7F50;
}
```

```html
<h1>Positioning Elements</h1>
<div id="container">
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <p id="p2"></p>
  <p id="p3"></p>
  <p id="p4"></p>
</div>
```

Can you explain what is happening here?

Comment: FYI, tags don't have color. _Elements_ do. Tags are just text in a file.

Comment: `position: relative;` is NOT the same as "absolute positioning" via `position: absolute;`.  If you don't need the automatic style of a `p` perhaps just use a `div`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When the container div has **position: relative**, it is in the normal document flow and takes up the full width of its parent by default. Thus, the background color extends to the full width of the browser.

When you set **position: absolute**, the container div is taken out of the normal flow and its width becomes only as wide as its content (stacked p elements). To maintain the full width of the browser for the background color, add width: 100% to the container div:

```
 

* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    h1 {
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    div#container {
        background-color: #00FFFF;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        width: 100%; /* Add this line */
    }
    p {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    #p1 {
      background-color: #A52A2A;
      position : relative;

    }
    #p2 {
      background-color: #DEB887;
      position : absolute;
      top : 65px;
      left : 65px;
    }
    #p3 {
      background-color: #5F9EA0;
    }
    #p4 {
      background-color: #FF7F50;
    }
    <h1>Positioning Elements</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <p id="p1"></p>
      <p id="p2"></p>
      <p id="p3"></p>
      <p id="p4"></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

because `#p2` is a relative element, relative element it's space is hold, and it's position is relative.

So the parent container just know relative element's space postion, don't know it's actual position.